# How do I simplify the expression (a^-1 + b^-1) ^-1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How do I simplify the expression ...

$$(a^{-1} + b^{-1}) ^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: As a note, this is a very important expression, particularly in electrical engineering and electronics for dealing with resistance and capacitance.

Answer (score 7):

If you have meant $$\left(a^{-1}+b^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$

it is equal to $$\frac1{a^{-1}+b^{-1}}=\frac1{\frac1a+\frac1b}=\frac{ab}{b+a}$$ multiplying the numerator & the denominator by $ab$

assuming $a,b$ to be non-zero numbers